# Restrict access to live site from public while showing small group the new site all on the same URL?

Tags: plugins

I am trying to come up with a way that I can put a WOrdPress site live on it;s final server for a client and have the site hidden from public.

It would show a dummy placeholder page to all visitor unless they enter a password or have a cookie set or IP matching...you get the idea.

So only a group of allowed people would view the live site and others would see a placeholder landing page while the site was being worked on.

Any ideas on a god easy solution?

I do not want to have to move any file or change URLS.

---

**Idea 1)**

There is a WOrdPress plugin that I have used before which allow the Admin users to view 1 WOrdPress theme while serving a different Theme to all other users.  THis allows you to keep the same URLs in place and allow access to the new theme/site while serving a different site to all other visitors.

I think this might be my best solution as I would simply create a simple placeholder page in the visitor WordPress theme.

---

I am curious of other simple solutions that could be done at a code level, any ideas?

Comment: Use a Plugin, it would be easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put code below into your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    is_user_logged_in() || auth_redirect();
});

function fpw_custom_login_message() {
    $message = '<p style="text-align: center">Until this site goes public you need to be registered to see the content<br />&nbsp;</p>';
    return $message;
}
add_filter('login_message', 'fpw_custom_login_message');
```